# Retornar list com Ajax método post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

Boa tarde a todos,

Estou com um problema que é o seguinte. Através de uma requisição Ajax eu retorno uma lista de objetos. Esta minha classe é só para carregar os dados que eu preciso enviar para a view que faz a chamada da procedure na controller por isso ela não está declarada como DbSet na classe context.

Quando fiz o código descrito abaixo asp.net mvc 6 deu certo, mas quando coloquei o mesmo codigo no asp.net core deu erro, parece que não consegue acessar as propriedades. ex: `alert(response.result[i].Correto)` aparece 'undefined', e se coloco só `alert(response.result)` aparece `Object object`. Mas a quantidade de resgistros que tem na lista aparece certo (`response.result.length`). Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Desconsiderem a '\' depois do sinal de menor, fiz isso para o código ficar completo.

Segue abaixo a classe, a action da controller e o codigo jquery com a requisição ajax:

```cs
public class RespostaProvaModel
    {

        public int QuestaoId { get; set; }
        public string TextoPergunta { get; set; }
        public string TextoResposta { get; set; }
        public bool Correto { get; set; }
    }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult <List<RespostaProvaModel>> CarregaProva(List<RespostaProvaModel> resultadoProva)
{
    List<RespostaProvaModel> resultadoFinal = new List<RespostaProvaModel>();

            foreach (RespostaProvaModel resposta in resultadoProva)
            {
                RespostaProvaModel resultado = _educ365Context.Respostas.Where(r => r.QuestaoId == resposta.QuestaoId)
                                   .Select(r => new RespostaProvaModel
                                   {
                                       QuestaoId = r.QuestaoId,
                                       TextoResposta = r.RespostaDescricao,
                                       Correto = (resposta.TextoResposta.ToLower().Equals(r.RespostaDescricao.ToLower()))
                                   }).FirstOrDefault();

                resultadoFinal.Add(resultado);
            }  
            return Json(new { result = resultadoFinal.ToList() });
}
```

Trecho do Ajax na view

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '@Url.Action("CarregaProva","Prova")',
     data: { resultadoProva },
     success: function (response) {
        alert("Tamanho: " + response.result.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < response.result.length;i++) {
           alert("Correto: " + response.result[i]);
        }
```

Comment: O alert não mostra o conteúdo de objetos. Use `console.log` para ver a estrutura dos dados. Aí vc pode analisar melhor.

Comment: Sam, usei o  console.log e apareceu a mesma coisa. Coloquei response.result[i].Correto, deveria aparecer true mas apareceu unfefined

Comment: Troque `response.result[i].Correto`  por `JSON.stringify(response.result[i])`, aparece o json correto?